# Converting Days/times to Time span

Tags: asp.net

Not found what I am looking for. I have codes written in asp and I am trying to convert them into timespan asp.net mvc:

```
   <%
    days = DateDiff("d",year(rs("create_dt")) & "-" 
                                              & month(rs("create_dt")) & "-" 
                                              & day(rs("create_dt")),date())
    if days=0 then days=1

    db_totalrecords=clng(rs("cnt"))
    periodcount=periodcount+db_totalrecords
    response.write db_totalrecords
   %>
```

Action method:

```
   public ActionResult ForcesDBValuesStat()
     {
        List<StatDBValues> myData;

        using (GenesEntities context = new GenesEntities())
        {
            myData = m_statsWallRepository.GetDBValues(context);
        }
        ViewBag["myBag"] = DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
        return View(myData); 
       }
```

Appreciate as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you got `create_dt` and `cnt` as `DateTime` and `Int32` variables in your viewbag I would say the following in c#/Razor syntax.

**Update**
The `ViewBag` is dynamic in mvc. This means that you can put inside it any thing you want to communicate to the view. Here I am only using it as an example. What you should be concerned about in regards to your original question is that if you subtract any two `DateTime` variables in c# you get a `TimeSpan` as the result. From there you can call to `TotalDays` to get the timespan expressed in days.

```
public ActionResult ForcesDBValuesStat()
{
    List<StatDBValues> myData;

    using (GenesEntities context = new GenesEntities())
    {
        myData = m_statsWallRepository.GetDBValues(context);
    }


    // set a "count" to be 
    // a random integer. 
    // should be comming from someware 
    // for example the database
    ViewBag.cnt = 123;
    // set the created date to a past date 
    ViewBag.create_dt = new DateTime(2015, 9, 13);
    return View(myData); 
}
```

```
@{
    var date = (DateTime)ViewBag.create_dt;
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var days = (today - date).TotalDays;
    var db_totalrecords = (int)ViewBag.cnt;
    if (days == 0) 
    {
         days = 1;
    }

}
    <h2>Test</h2>
    @days
```

Comment: Error I am getting: Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type

Comment: Ok I suspect you don't have a controller and/or you are not initializing your ViewBag variables . You need some training on mvc in order for any of this to make reason.

Comment: Yes I am learning. In my controller I am using List<OfData> using context. Am I be able to create a viewbag as follows or I need to take some other approach: ViewBag["myBag"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();

Comment: please update your question with the code inside your action method plus the actual `OfData` class declaration and if possible I will try to update my answer

Comment: Just updated my code. not sure about view bag though

Comment: @TicketForLessUK If this answers your question please mark as answer

Comment: I am still on this and will let you know.

Comment: Adding ViewBag.CreateDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10); in controller is working fine. but I do not want to input 2015, 10, 10 direct where the system should take dates from the database and then calculate using current date. Any advice on that?

Comment: @TicketForLessUK I believe that thats another question. But sould be easy to change the above code to work the same way from DateTimes coming for the database. Instead of the ViewBag work with your model.